# How to get distinct months from array containing dates

Tags: php

I have an array with dates. ie.

```
array(
    0 => '2016-08-01',
    1 => '2016-07-15',
    2 => '2016-07-01'
);
```

I need to get the distinct months in array. ie.

```
array(
    0 => 7,
    1 => 8
);
```

I need it to do a foreach to show: June - Juy - August with the distinct months from the dates array. (That part I know how)

Comment: not clear what you are asking

Comment: `$result = array_unique(array_map(function ($value) { return (new DateTime($value))->format('n'); }, $data));`

Comment: @MarkBaker Please decide whether you wish to post that commented solution as an answer, then please delete your comment so as to not role model incorrect UI behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reformat the date using a combination of [`array_map`](http://php.net/array-map), [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime), and [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array-unique) to achieve that result.

```
$arr = array(
    0 => '2016-08-01',
    1 => '2016-07-15',
    2 => '2016-07-01'
);
$dates = array_unique(array_map(function($date) {
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->format('n');
}, $arr));

var_dump($dates);
```

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "7"
}
```

Of course, it's important to note this results in two dates like `2015-08-11` and `2016-08-04` both showing up as one value in the array. So it's not entirely clear why you would want to do this, but this will meet your specified requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This is the loop you need :

```
<?php
$arr = array( '2016-08-01',
              '2016-07-15',
              '2016-07-01' );
$months = array(); // EMPTY ARRAY FOR MONTHS.
foreach ( $arr as $date ) // VISIT EACH DATE IN ARRAY.
{ $mon = substr( $date,5,2 ); // EXTRACT THE MONTH DIGITS.
  if ( ! in_array( $mon,$months ) ) // IF MONTH IS NOT IN ARRAY
     array_push( $months,$mon ); // INSERT THE MONTH DIGITS.
}
var_dump( $months );
?>
```

Edit : display month name :

```
<?php
$arr = array( '2016-08-01',
              '2016-07-15',
              '2016-07-01' );
$months = array(); // EMPTY ARRAY FOR MONTHS.
foreach ( $arr as $date ) // VISIT EACH DATE IN ARRAY.
{ $mon = substr( $date,5,2 ); // EXTRACT THE MONTH DIGITS.
  if ( ! in_array( $mon,$months ) ) // IF MONTH IS NOT IN ARRAY
     { array_push( $months,$mon ); // INSERT THE MONTH DIGITS.
       echo date ("F",mktime( null,null,null,$mon,1 ) ); // ◄ MONTH NAME!!!
     }
}
?>
```

Edit #2 : storing month names in array :

```
<?php
$arr = array( '2016-08-01',
              '2016-07-15',
              '2016-07-01' );
$months = array(); // EMPTY ARRAY FOR MONTHS.
foreach ( $arr as $date ) // VISIT EACH DATE IN ARRAY.
{ $mon = date("F",mktime( null,null,null,substr( $date,5,2 ),1 ) ); // EXTRACT MONTH.
  if ( ! in_array( $mon,$months ) ) // IF MONTH IS NOT IN ARRAY
     array_push( $months,$mon ); // INSERT MONTH NAME IN ARRAY.
}
var_dump( $months );
?>
```

Comment: that is the long version I wanted to avoid, array_map() will do the trick

Comment: Jose, I guess the loop part wasn't clear. I wan to do a foreach to show: June - Juy - August with the distinct months from the dates array.

Comment: @jesse94, last edit to my answer : month names stored in array (for further use).

Answer (score 0):

Just use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) on each of your dates array entries to retrieve the chars 5 to 7, then store them in a new array :

```
$dates = array(
    0 => '2016-08-01',
    1 => '2016-07-15',
    2 => '2016-07-01');
$months = array();

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $months[] = (int)substr($date, 5, 2);
}
$months = array_unique($months); // Remove duplicates
sort($months);
```